# Diffie-Hellman Library for c++ and java

Tags: java, android, c++, diffie-hellman

I want to exchange a public key between a c++ application and and android application.
I decided to use [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). On the C++ side [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70330/Implementation-of-Diffie-Hellman-Algorithm-of-Key) library looks promising for generating the keys with c++. Now I am looking for an implementation for java to generate the keys on the android smartphone.

What libraries would you suggest, also on the c++ side?
In the end i want to share the public key as a string via UDP.

kind regards

Comment: Have you read the docs on [the Java Cryptography Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long time ago I used Crypto++ for the C++ which worked well for me and has support for many different algorithms.

http://www.cryptopp.com/

For android the KeyAgreement class can be used on some JavaVM, it is initialized with a String to choose the algorithm. You could try to instantiate it with "DiffieHellman" and see if you get an instance.

According to Java7 docs, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.html - 
"*Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard KeyAgreement algorithm:
DiffieHellman*"

Test it and see if that includes dalvik or not.